# Paginator, how to make the first page and the last static and puts to dots between

Tags: php, html, css, zend-framework, pagination

So I need something like this:

prev 1 ... 5 6 7 8 ... 56 next

this is what i have in my view:

```
<?php if ($this->pageCount>1):?>
<div class="paginator">

<!-- Ссылка на предыдущую страницу -->
<?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
  <a class="next" href="<?php echo $this->url(array( 'id' => $this->element_id,'sortby'=>$this->sortby,'page' => $this->previous), $this->route.'_pagination'); ?>">
     <?=$this->translator()->_('previous');?>
  </a>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- Нумерованные ссылки на страницы -->
<?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>
  <?php if ($page != $this->current): ?>
    <a class="numbers" href="<?php echo $this->url(array( 'id' => $this->element_id,'sortby'=>$this->sortby, 'page' => $page), $this->route.'_pagination'); ?>">
        <?php echo $page; ?>
    </a>
  <?php else: ?>
        <a class="active" href="#"><?php echo $page; ?></a>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<!-- Ссылка на следующую страницу -->
<?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
  <a class="prev" href="<?php echo $this->url(array( 'id' => $this->element_id,'sortby'=>$this->sortby,'page' => $this->next), $this->route.'_pagination'); ?>">
    <?=$this->translator()->_('next');?>
  </a>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and this is my controller, function index:

```
public function indexAction()
{
        if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $mapper = new Album_Model_Mapper_Album();
    $user_id = $this->_request->getParam('id');

        $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($mapper->getUserAlbums($user_id));

        $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
        $settings = $this->getFrontController()->getParam('bootstrap')->getOption('settings');
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page'));
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage($settings['albums_per_page_profile']);
        $paginator->setPageRange(4);
        $this->view->route = 'albums';
        $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
    $this->view->user_id = $user_id;
    $this->view->current_page = $this->_getParam('page') ? $this->_request->getParam('page') : 1;
    if((!isset($this->view->current_page) or $this->view->current_page==1) and $user_id==$this->getStorage()->read()->id){
        $mapperFilters = new Filters_Model_Mapper_PhotoFilters();
        $this->view->filter = $mapperFilters->fetchBySql($mapperFilters->getUserPhotos($this->getStorage()->read()->id)->limit(1), true, true);
    }
    echo $this->view->render('albums.phtml');

}
```

by now i have something like this:

prev 2 3 4 5 next

i don't know how to change that to this:

prev 1 ... 5 6 7 8 ... 56 next

please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use my own created pagination class, where change just names for the first and last change and You can change just some patterns.
Also, if You have questions how to use the class, then contact me.
http://danielspitkevics.id.lv/index.php?r=site/viewscripts&id=10

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to replace your pagination class and use a new one, this one will do exactly what you want:

http://www.catchmyfame.com/2007/07/28/finally-the-simple-pagination-class/

Answer (score 0):

You can take help from following script, which i used in mostly for pagination work.

page.php

```
<?php
   include('db_connect.php');   // include your code to connect to DB.
   $page_id = isset($_GET['page_id']) ? $_GET['page_id'] : 1;
   $tbl_name="city";        //your table name
   $records_per_page = 5;

   /* Pagination Starts here */
   $query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
   $result= mysql_query($query);

   if($page_id==1)
   {
    $start_id=0;
    $end_id=$records_per_page;
   }
   else
   {
    $start_id=$records_per_page*($page_id-1);
    $end_id=$records_per_page*$page_id;
   }

   $start_limit = mysql_num_rows($result)-1 - $start_id;
   if($end_id>mysql_num_rows($result))
    $end_limit = 0;
   else
    $end_limit = mysql_num_rows($result)-$end_id;

   $select_limit=$start_limit-$end_limit+1;

   for ($i = $start_limit,$j=0; $i >= $end_limit; $i--,$j++) 
   {
    if(!mysql_data_seek($result, $i)) 
    {
    echo "Cannot seek to row $i: " . mysql_error() . "\n";
    continue;
    }

    if (!($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) 
    {
    continue;
    }

   // your code to print data, i have echo city name from city table.
    echo $row['city_name'].'<br>';
   }

   if(mysql_num_rows($result))
   {
$temp=(int)(mysql_num_rows($result)/$records_per_page);

if($temp< (ceil((mysql_num_rows($result)/$records_per_page))))
    $total_pages=ceil((mysql_num_rows($result)/$records_per_page));
else if($temp==floor((mysql_num_rows($result)/$records_per_page)))
    $total_pages=floor((mysql_num_rows($result)/$records_per_page));

echo '<div class="pagination">';
if($page_id==1)
{
    echo '<span class="disabled" title="First Page"><<</span>';
    echo '<span class="disabled" title="Previous Page"><</span>';                   
}
else
{
        echo '<a href="page.php?page_id=1" title="First Page"><<</a>';
        echo '<a href="page.php?page_id='.($page_id-1).'" title="Previous Page"><</a>';             
}

if($page_id<=5)
    $min = $page_id;
else
    $min = $page_id-5;
if($total_pages<($page_id+5))
    $max = $total_pages;
else
    $max = $page_id+5;
while($min<=$page_id)
{
    if($min==$page_id)
        echo '<span class="current" title="Current Page">'.$page_id.'</span>';
    else
    {
        echo '<a href="page.php?page_id='.$min.'" title="Page '.$min.'">'.$min.'</a>';
    }
    $min++;
}

    $i = $page_id +1;
while($i<=$max)
{
    echo '<a href="page.php?page_id='.$i.'" title="Page '.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
    $i++;
}

if($page_id==$total_pages)
{
    echo '<span class="disabled" title="Next Page">></span>';
    echo '<span class="disabled" title="Last Page">>></span>';                  
}
else
{
    echo '<a href="page.php?page_id='.($page_id+1).'" title="Next Page">></a>';
    echo '<a href="page.php?page_id='.$total_pages.'" title="Last Page">>></a>';
}
echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

style.css

```
    div.pagination {
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 3px;
}

div.pagination a {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #AAAADD;

    text-decoration: none; /* no underline */
    color: #000099;
}

div.pagination a:hover, div.pagination a:active {
    border: 1px solid #000099;
    color: #000;
}

div.pagination span.current {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin: 2px;
        border: 1px solid #000099;

        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #000099;
        color: #FFF;
    }
div.pagination span.disabled {
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;

    color: #DDD;
}
```